# Producer consumer variant java BlockingQueues

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, queue

I'm working on a variant of the producer consumer problem in Java. I have a producer thread creating objects, that are put into an priority blocking queue, and then passed into the main container, the controller,  which is a bounded buffer.

The reason for the queue is that when the main container has a certain % of Object A, it will only accept objects of type B, and some other scenarios that we have been asked to look at. 
I'm having trouble figuring out what is going wrong with the code, the debugger is just jumping from in.offer in InQueue, and in.push in Producer. Any direction or advice would be appreciated.

```
    import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;

        public class InQueue implements Runnable {

        Controller c;
        private PriorityBlockingQueue in;

        public InQueue(Controller c) {
            this.c = c;
            in = new PriorityBlockingQueue();
        }

        public void push(C c) {

            in.offer(c);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    C temp = (C) in.take(); //will block if empty
                    c.arrive(temp);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {} // TODO
            }
        }
    }

public class Controller {

    private BoundedBuffer buffer;
    private int used;


    Controller(int capacity) {
        this.buffer = new BoundedBuffer(capacity);
        used = 0;
    }


    public void arrive(C c) {
        try {
            buffer.put(c);
            used++;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { } //TODO
    }

    public C depart() {
        C temp = null; //BAD IDEA?
        try {
            temp = (C)buffer.take();
            used--;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { } //TODO
        return temp; //could be null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not compiling because of the wrong way your using generics. Another thing is that there is no default implementation of BoundedBuffer. Below I made a working implementation for the producer - consumer problem below with blocking queues. Have a look and correct your mistakes.

```
package concurrency;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class Producer<T> {
    private final BlockingQueue<T> queue;
    private final Consumer consumer;
    private static volatile boolean isShutdown;
    private final static Object lock = new Object();

    public Producer() {
        this.queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<T>();
        this.consumer = new Consumer();
    }

    public void start() {
        consumer.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            isShutdown = true;
        }
        consumer.interrupt();
    }

    public void put(T obj) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (isShutdown)
                throw new IllegalStateException("Consumer Thread is not active");
        }
        queue.put(obj);
    }

    private class Consumer extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    if (isShutdown)
                        break;
                }

                T t = takeItem();
                // do something with 't'
                if(t!=null)
                printItem(t);
            }
        }

        private void printItem(T t) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }

        private T takeItem() {
            try {
                return queue.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Producer<Integer> producer = new Producer<Integer>();
        producer.start();
        for (int i = 0; i <20; i++) {
            producer.put(i);
            if (i >= 7)
                Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        producer.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: No mate, I can do that, what you listed. The generics do need tidying up I'll admit, but I don't think that's the problem. Also, I have the bounded buffer coded myself.
The setup is producer -> BlockingQueue -> BoundedByffer -> OutBlockingQueue -> consumer.